# Post form data to url with function in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have some data for creating model and I also have form of that model so, user can also create model instance, now what I wanted to do is - creating the model in same way as user fill and submit the form.

I want to do so because I am adding some additional data with `form_valid` to that model, for example - `form.instance = self.request.user` and many others and also having some custom validations.

For doing that what I thought is, If I create a form and put the data in it and post it to url. I don't know wheather it is good idea or not, but any one who can help ?

Comment: Could you describe about your detail problem? Want to add more data after form_valid, right?

Comment: @seuling, See I have two views (view1, view2), `view1` is `createview` and `view2` is some other view, now I have some data in view2 and wanted to post that in `view1` , so that a model instance will create with all properties that `form_valid` of `view1` append in it.

Comment: It's too ambiguous. Could you upload your view1 and view2?

Comment: You should abstract out the code from `form_valid` and call it from both views.